# Should I use the new Symfony 4 file structure with 3.3 & 3.4?

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm wondering if it makes sense to use the Symfony 4 file structure (as described in [Fabian's post](http://fabien.potencier.org/symfony4-directory-structure.html)) for projects running Symfony 3.3 and 3.4?

The Architecture page in the documentation for [3.3](https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/quick_tour/the_architecture.html), [3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/quick_tour/the_architecture.html) and [4.0](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/quick_tour/the_architecture.html) all show the version 3.* directory structure so I'm not sure where the canonical information is and thus I'm not 100% sure it's either a good idea nor what the "final" decision is.

Comment: Take a look at this https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#upgrading-existing-applications-to-flex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is good idea – if you plan to start using Symfony Flex (the next big thing in Symfony world), the directory structure used Symfony 4 is [required](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/flex.html#upgrading-existing-applications-to-flex). Last version of Symfony Standard Edition [will be 3.4](https://twitter.com/fabpot/status/866345389397594115), so if you want your application to keep up to date, it's better choice to start use that structure now, than moving and review tens (or hundreds) of files later.

Documentation is not yet updated – current master version (4.0) is just clone of 3.4.

Comment: The problem is that 4.0 is still very much a work in progress.  If you shift to the new structure now then you may find yourself shifting again when the final version is released.

Comment: @Cerad posible changes between current version of 4.0 and final would be minor.

Comment: And you know this how?  Take a look at what happened between 2.7 and 2.8/3.0.  Lost and lots of last minute changes.

Comment: @Cerad He is asking about directory structure. All changes of directory structure were between major versions (v2.x and v3.x). They were minor and not kind of *„last minute“* – don't you remember [long discussion on Github](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/issues/584#issuecomment-23148928)?